# load data in ngrx effect with dispatch an action before using route guard

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

My auth is based on **NGRX**
so when the page starts loading  I got all roles and
then get logged in.

but when I start using route guard,
route gourd start working before user data get loading

how can I wait for user load action to be done then start using **canActivate**
I try below solution but it's not working

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, OnDestroy {
private unsubscribe: Subject<any>;

constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private router: Router,
  private alertService: ToastrService, private authService: AuthService) {
  this.unsubscribe = new Subject();
}
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.unsubscribe.next();
  this.unsubscribe.complete();
}
getFromStoreOrAPI(): Observable<any> {
  return this.store.pipe(
    select(isUserLoaded),
    tap((data: boolean) => {
      if (!data) {
        this.store.dispatch(new UserRequested());
      }
    }),
    take(1)
  );
}
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

  return this.getFromStoreOrAPI().pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      this.store.pipe(
        select(isLoggedIn),
        map(loggedIn => {
          if (!loggedIn) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/login');
            return false;
          } else {
            this.store.pipe(
              select(currentUserRoles),
              map((userRoles: Role[]) => {
                //.......
              }),
              takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
            ).subscribe();
          }
        }),
      )
    ),
    catchError(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/login'))
  );
}

}
```

Comment: you can use the resolver to wait for the response.
https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: @surendra-kumar  how can I use a resolver in a route guard ?!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` to wait until `loaded` flag is `true`.

Here is approach I took with my `auth.guard.ts` :

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authFacade.loaded$.pipe(
      filter(loaded => !!loaded),
      mergeMap(() => this.authFacade.userAccount$),
      map(userAccount => {
        if (!userAccount) this.authFacade.redirectLoginPage(state.url);
        return !!userAccount;
      }),
      first()
    );
  }
```

In my case, main app component is dispatching an action `CheckAuth` to check if user is already authenticated, and then set `loaded` flag.

It should work with some adaptation for your need. But main difference is the use of `filter` which avoid to continue the workflow if user checking is not done, and force waiting for the value.

Of course, be sure to set `loaded` value in all the case after receiving response (authenticated or not), or in case of any error.

Here is a potential adaptation for your case :

```
authLoaded$ = this.store.pipe(select(authLoaded));
authAccount$ = this.store.pipe(select(authAccount));

canActivate(...) {
  return userLoaded$.pipe(    
    tap(loaded => {
      if (!loaded) {
        this.store.dispatch(new UserRequested());
      }
    }),
    filter(loaded => !!loaded),
    mergeMap(() => authAccount$),
    map(authAccount => {
      if (!authAccount.loggedIn) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/login');
        return false;
      }

      if (!authAccount.roles?.length) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/forbidden');
        return false;
      }

      // do some extra stuff...

      return true;
    }),
    first()
  );
}
```

I renamed `isUserLoaded` to `authLoaded` to clearly indicate the status of authentication loading (you can use also ready or not for instance). But not necessary user.

I created also a new selector `authAccount` which returns an object with at least 2 things :

- loggedIn : true/false if user is logged in
- roles: array of user roles.
  But you can add of course `user` property, with user details.

This is a composed selector from different parts of your state.
With it, your code is more clear and maintable, you receive a complete status of your current authentication user.

Maybe some typos is possible, I wrote the code directly in my answer without testing it.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: in my case do you know how ?

Comment: I've edited my answer with more details and adapted my original code.